# Does MySQL have a feature like the Stretch database in sqlserver

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, stretch

Does MySQL have a feature like Stretch database in Sqlserver.
I would like to have an architecture like Stretch database in SQLServer/Azure in MySQL/AWS.
Lets say I have an Orders table which has data from the past 20 years but I really do not need any data which is older than 2 years.I need to move that old data from my local database to AWS(Mysql) so that my performance stays good locally.Also at the same time if somebody queries old data it should still retrieve data locally from AWS(Mysql). Can we have a similar setup in MySql/AWS.
Thanks